# SAPUI5 build GeoMap based on picture, shopfloor

Tags: sapui5, imagemap, geomap

I need to build an application which shows a floor plan of a building (shopfloor). I also need to place some text boxes at defined positions with some data, like a popup. But I need several of them and all needs to be opened/active without user interaction.

How can I achieve this? I ran through Analytics Map and GeoMap which looks great and especially GeoMap with containers seems to fit. https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.vbm.GeoMap/sample/sap.ui.vbm.sample.GeoMapCharts

However, I don't need a world map. I need a map based on my own picture/image showing the floor plan of a building. Anyone ever build something like that or any ideas how to solve this?

I was able to load my custom image as map into GeoMap. But it gets repeated several times and doesn't zoom correct. Any way to fix this?

```
buildMap: function () {
        var oGeoMap = this.getView().byId("GeoMap");
        var oMapConfig = {
            "MapProvider": [{
                "name": "HEREMAPS",
                "type": "",
                "description": "",
                "tileX": "256",
                "tileY": "256",
                "maxLOD": "1",
                "copyright": "Tiles Courtesy of HERE Maps",
                "Source": [{
                    "id": "s1",
                    "url": "images/HS1.jpg"
                }]
            }],
            "MapLayerStacks": [{
                "name": "DEFAULT",
                "MapLayer": {
                    "name": "layer1",
                    "refMapProvider": "HEREMAPS",
                    "opacity": "1.0",
                    "colBkgnd": "RGB(255,255,255)"
                }
            }]
        };
        oGeoMap.setMapConfiguration(oMapConfig);
        oGeoMap.setRefMapLayerStack("DEFAULT");
```

[image: Map after adding custom image as map provider]

PS: I know there was a ImageMap class but it is marked as deprecated without any replacement.

Comment: I would use a HTML Canvas control

Comment: Thank you @Bernard this helps me a lot. I was able to solve it by using Canvas.